# Smallest possible valid .tif file

Tags: image, hex, tiff, filesize, hex-editors

I'm curious about what the smallest possible valid tif file is(still opens without errors, I'm using IrFanView to test validity for this purpose). The smallest I've been able to put together through a hex editor so far is 72 bytes. We're using this for a health check that runs many thousands of times per day, and would like a file as small as possible. I realize at this point, going much smaller would be a trivial difference, but was curious if anything could be trimmed off of this to make it smaller, or if there's a different way to go about making a tiny file. Here's the hex for the image that's 72 bytes:

```
49 49 2A 00 0A 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 00 01 03 00 
01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 01 03 00 01 00 00 00 
01 00 00 00 03 01 03 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
11 01 04 00 01 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 17 01 04 00 
01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
```

Image here:
[lil.tiff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8Deq.png)

***Update:***
We've done a little more research and switched to Big Endian Encoding. We've been able to create a 46 byte file using the following:

```
   4D 4D 00 2A 00 00 00 08 
   00 03 01 00 00 03 00 00
   00 01 00 01 00 00 01 01 
   00 03 00 00 00 01 00 01 
   00 00 01 11 00 03 00 00 
   00 01 00 00 00 00
```

From everything I've seen, attributes 01 10(width), 01 10(height), and 01 11(strip offsets) are required 12 byte attributes. The 03 on line two above indicates the three attributes, changing this to 2, 1, or 0 and removing any combination of the attributes results in an invalid image. I've tried adding compression(attribute 01 13), but apparently the file size is small enough it still results in a loss. At this point, is there anything that can be done to shrink the file size(mostly out of curiosity sake). 
New Image Here: [Updated 46bytes.tiff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOP61.png)

Comment: Your linked images are PNGs, not TIFs?

Comment: yes, very strange